# R subset elements specifying column and row if each element

Tags: r, subset

How should I subset a matrix specifying both the line and the column of each item ? I'm currently using `sapply` but I don't find that particularly elegant:

```
> mat <- data.frame(a=c(1,2,3),b=c(7,6,5))
> mat
  a b
1 1 7
2 2 6
3 3 5
> rowSel <- 1:3
> colSel <- c(1,2,1)
> sapply(rowSel,function(i){mat[i,colSel[i]]})
[1] 1 6 3
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A shorter way:

```
mat[cbind(rowSel, colSel)]
#[1] 1 6 3
```

This uses the indexing by a twocolumn matrix. The first column contains the index of the row, the second column contains the index of the column. Each row of the twocolumn matrix indexes a element of the matrix `mat`.

Comment: Would you also have a quick and easy way to handle NAs in the indexes (should return NA) ?

Comment: What do you mean? With `colSel <- c(2,1, NA)` the last element of the result is `NA`. Would you please edit your question to describe the new example? http://stackoverflow.com/posts/36286357/edit

Comment: You are right, It was complaining on my real life problem about NA but for an other reason, sorry.